# Pull a value from a parent class in Javascript for GTM

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I am having troubles using javascript to pull in a value from a parent class on a button click. I am going to fire the javascript on the button select and need it to climb up the Dom tree and pull out the value from the "product-sku" class. After digging into this post https://gomakethings.com/climbing-up-and-down-the-dom-tree-with-vanilla-javascript/ I know I will have to preface my the script on the button select but am unsure if I can move this way through the tree, thoughts?

```
<div class="review-sku-line">
            <div class="ratings">
    <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='xxxx/review/product/list/id/123456/category/117/'; return false;">No Reviews</a></span>
</div>

            <div class="product-sku">
                <span><strong>Code:</strong> 7777</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
                            <form class="add-form cart-update-flag" method="post" action="xxxxx/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR3dUuaHRtbA,,/product/123456/form_key/cV1MQZ1w/">
                    <input type="hidden" name="block_name" value="xxxxxx/_list_item_render_gridview">

                    <div class="qty-control small">
                        <button type="button" for="qty_prod_123456" class="qty-ctrl-sub button">
                            <span class="grey-btn"><i class="icon-minus"></i></span>
                        </button>
                        <input id="qty_prod_123456" type="text" class="qty" name="qty" value="1">
                        <button type="button" for="qty_prod_123456" class="qty-ctrl-add button">
                            <span class="orange-btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>


                    <button class="button btn btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="submit">
                        <span>Add to Cart</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions or advice!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to define a variable, which will contain the value of your target object. When the event (click) occurs the value will be available with this variable.

Create a new variable and select "DOM Element". Then use "CSS Selector" with following value: div.product-sku

If there are multiple sku-values on a page, you can use this function to return the value of the next matching parent object:

```
  function findElementWithSelector (elem) {

    // Define your selector value
    selector = "product-sku";

    // Get closest match
    for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) { 
      if ( elem.hasAttribute("class") && elem.getAttribute(class) === selector) {
        return elem;
      }
    }
  };
```

You will need to put this function within a Tag, that fires as soon as possible on every page (like a "common functions" HTML Tag).
Then you can use a variable to retrieve the value of the click element:
(custom JavaScript variable)

```
  if({{Click Element}} != "")
    return findElementWithSelector({{Click Element}});
```